# How to check DTO data with property annotation

Tags: c#, .net, annotations, decorator, dto

I am having a hard time coming to terms with 20+ string type properties returned as `optional` from 3rd party API.

Example:

```
Subject {
    subjectId (integer, optional),
    shortName (string, optional),
    shortCode (string, optional),
    colour (string, optional),
    description (string, optional),
    name (string, optional)
}
```

In my code, after I get my hands on the list of Subjects I have to check each and every optional property to avoid `object reference exceptions`. In the case of Subjects that's very simple:

```
var subjectId = subjectId ?? -1;
var name = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? name : String.Empty;
var boolValue = boolValue ?? false; // if a boolean value is optional
```

I am requesting data using Web API so JSON response is deserialized into data transfer object(s).

Example:

```
public class SubjectDto {
    public int? subjectId { get; set; }
    public string shortName { get; set; }
    public string shortCode { get; set; }
    public string colour { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

So, I was wondering if it is possible to decorate DTO class properties with annotations to automatically handle the checks when JSON is deserialized?

```
subjects = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SubjectDto>();
```

While it nice and simple for `Subjects`, it would reduce the clutter of having to check 20+ string, int, boolean properties for valid data in some other classes.

Comment: Did you tried `DefaultValueAttribute` for missing properties?

Comment: @Fabio I have not tried ``DefaultValue`` attribute because of ``A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.`` I would need to do a bit of testing later to see if this would work for me.

Comment: Although http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultValueAttributeIgnore.htm suggests it can be used. I guess it would depend on how ``response.Content.ReadAsAsync`` deserializes data internally.

Comment: If you use `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync` which return string, then you can use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubjectDto>(jsonString);`. Which in this case will use `DefaultValueAttribute` for missing properties

Comment: @Fabio I've had a bit of time to try this out and I am not very happy. All my empty strings were reset to ``NULL``s. And it looks like I still have to deal with optional ``int``eger and ``bool``ean values.

Comment: Another option is to try auto-property notation introduce in C# 6.0 ``public int subjectId { get; set; } = -1;`` although I am not sure how it will react to ``int?`` type or receiving ``NULL``.